# Find the inverse for arbitrary k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need to find a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h (all of which are not zero)

such that for all k is in Real number, show A is invertible or this can't happen

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\d&k&e\\f&g&h
\end{array}\;\begin{array}{c}\end{array}\right)$$

My answer was this can't happen, but I don't know what the answer is.
And I couldn't provide a complete proof to support my answer.

I assume that a, ~, h are all 1. Then use det and element row operation I got 0 determinant for all k.

And the general determinant for this with Sarrus's rule is

det(A) = k(ah-cf) + g(cd - ae) + b(ef - dh)

What should I do next? This is invertible or non-invertible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to choose $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ such that the determinant is non-zero for all $k$, i.e., the matrix is invertible for all $k$.

Note that as you have $$\det(A) = k(ah-cf) + g( cd-ae) + b(ef-dh)$$
First lets cut the dependence on $k$ in the determinant, i.e., set $ah-cf = 0$, i.e., $ah=cf$. Hence, now the determinant is (eliminating $a$)
$$\det(A) = g\left(cd-\dfrac{cfe}h\right) + b(ef-dh) = - \dfrac{(dh-ef)(bh-cg)}h$$
Now choose $b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ such that the determinant is non-zero.